# what is the simplest way to implement affiliate system?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, web, affiliate

I know a website which provide me some service.

I get an increasing discount if I refer people to buy this service form that site.

The site doesn't has an already made affiliates system

I communicate with the site,

and got this reply from them:

> Unfortunately, at the moment, we do not have any kind of affiliate
>   link and ID scheme in operation, however we would be keen to explore
>   setting one up. Could you clarify what you mean exactly? Would you
>   want your own email address? And you would put our site on your own
>   website so that we can track your booking?
>
> We are keen to work with you so just let us know what would be
>   required!

How can I establish a quick affiliate system (for me only, not generic scale-able one) ?

tracking pixel?
cookie?

I'm new to all of this

Comment: Buy it. Yup. That's the easy way. (This is not an appropriate question for here. Perhaps the question can be refined? I know not ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:
**1st Option:**

- Post `http://example.com/buy_this_service?ref=your-own-unique-ID` link text in the wild.
- Tell the company to to track `$_GET["ref"]` in their `service/index.php` file.

If the `example.com` company in question can not/ will not do anything, then you could do:
**2nd Option:**

- Post `http://your-own-domain.com/buy-this-amazing-service` link text.
- Silently track every visit by logging their IP, Time, Location, Unique-or-not etc..
- Redirect `http://your-own-domain.com/buy-this-amazing-service` to `http://example.com/service`

---

In 1st case, `example.com` need to capture and process the `Ref ID` as soon as visitor lands on their page, which should be the `buy-this` page(the one where link was pointing).
So, user lands, site records that `Elad (referrer)` sent this visitor. If visitor buy, they credit `Elad`, if not, then they do nothing.
From here, no matter our Ref ID stays there in the URL or not. We don't need need it now. The instance is already recorded.

If the site is already logging IP, then you should ask them to go with 1st case. Or, in a hackish way, in 2nd option,  on `your-domain.com/amazing-service` page, capture visitor's IP try to pass it to `example.com` using `GET` method.

Comment: regarding option 1st: there is a problem as after I direct somebody to their site he can press on another link and then the query string will be gone.

Comment: your last suggestion: redirect won't help as their site need to support IP logging

Comment: Edited the answer to answer your concerns..

Comment: For a simple service this might be ok. But normally you want to track the referrer. So you do not send the PartnerID. You request a script or image on the page which contains a unique token and creates the affiliate-backlink for you. This prevent abuse of the affiliate system.